# How to upload image form angular 5 to laravel storage?

Tags: angular, laravel, file-upload, angular5

I have an Angular 5 app, and in one of my component, I have a file input with name="logo", and I created a method to create a FormData when the input is change. I have an upload button in the same component and the click event is call the this.http.post(.../logo, FormData, {the header}).
In the laravel I have a LogoController with this method:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

class LogoController extends Controller{

    public function postLogo(Request $request){
       $file = $request->file('image');
       $filename = 'test.jpg';
       if($file){
           Storage::disk('local')->put($filename, File::get($file));
       }
       return response()->json(['file' => $file], 201);
    }
}
```

And this does not work. How to do this properly?

**Edited:**
Angular code:

logo.component.html:

```
<h1>Logo upload<h1>
<input type="file" name="logo" (change)="onFileSelected($event)">
<button type="button" (click)="onUploadLogo()">Upload</button>
```

logo.component.ts:

```
import { LogoService } from './../logo.service';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-logo',
  templateUrl: './logo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./logo.component.scss']
})
export class LogoComponent{
  logo: FormData;
  constructor(private logoService: LogoService){}

  onFileSelected(event){
    const fd = new FormData();
    const selectedFile = <File>event.target.files[0];
    fd.append('logo', selectedFile, selectedFile.name);
    this.logo = fd;
  }

  onUploadLogo(): void{
    if(this.logo){
      this.logoService.uploadLogo(this.logo).subscribe(
         res => {
           console.log(res);
         }
      );
    }
  }
}
```

logo.service.ts:

```
uploadLogo(logo: FormData): Observable<any>{
  const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  return this.http.post('http://homestead.test/api/logo, logo, {headers: headers});
}
```

Comment: You need to decode the Image if it arrives on base64format in to an image. How does the image is arriving to your laravel controller?

Comment: Show you angular code

Comment: I edited the post, now you can see my angular code.